# Need to modified variable value in visualforce/apex/salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, global-variables

My code in gobal footer component -

```
   <div id="copyright">
            &copy; {!$Label.copyright}
          </div>
```

It is displaying in page`"© Copyright 2012 "`

I am new in Salesforce. I just want to modified text with

```
"© Copyright 2013 "
```

In place of 2012 I want to use 2013...

What I have tried ??

1. Checked custom label
2. `$Label` is global variable search for copyright...

Please help me if I missed some basic part to check !!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to setup--> create--> custom labels you should see a label by name copyright click on it and the value should say "copyright 2012...." change the value there to 2013.

Hope this helps

**UPDATE:**

check this out if you are looking here:
[image]

[image]

**One final check /suggestion check your view and try to see if it is showing all the custom labels and not filtered.**

[image]

Comment: When I checked ... copyright is not present.. Can you please Tell me where else I can check !! Thanks

Comment: @learner $lable refers to custom labels http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_label.htm

Comment: you should be able to see the label by name copyright, the text should be a value in the custom field

Comment: can you get on chat we can figure out what could be happening there

Comment: I am checking... but that label is not present... May be some other name ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9140/discussion-between-rao-and-learner)

Comment: just in case you are unable to figure out post  a screenshot of the custom label and also the view name if you can so that we can verify if there are filters blocking the label.

Comment: Thanks @rao I got it....  thanks for helping me out... +1 and answer accepted !!

Comment: @learner anytime pal :)